# What to do with aftermarket radiator as far as installing engine coolant sensor

Tags: engine, coolant, sensor, buick

[image]
2002 buick century custom 3.1
I bought an aftermarket radiator for 2002 buick century custom 3.1. The new radiator doesn't seem to have a place for the engine coolant sensor. What should I do? Is it the wrong radiator or do I hook it up in different place?

Comment: A picture of the car is not really helpful, but a picture of both radiators would be.

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple options available. Check with whoever sold you the part before assuming any of the following are possible.

- Take it back and get a refund.
- Take the new and old radiator back and have them see the differences. They might have given you the wrong one and having the original part to compare will make it useful to find the one that fits.
- Modify the new radiator to use the coolant sensor. This is **not** recommended because it can end up damaging the part or costing more than buying it again.